# Bundling Spring components into a library so that other projects can choose to use some of them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

If I have a set of useful reusable Spring components how can I make them available as a library such that other projects can use just whatever subset of those components are useful to them?

E.g. I have 4 classes, `X1`, `X2`, `X3` and `X4`, each annotated with `@Component` (or `@Service`, `@Controller` or whatever) and I want to bundle them into a library.

Then I have project A that's only interested in using `X1` and `X3` and another project B that's only interested in using `X3` and `X4`.

How do projects A and B selectively enable just the components that they are interested in?

I'm using Spring Boot so I guess I could annotate each of my components with `@ConditionalOnProperty`, e.g. I could annotate `X1` etc. like so:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty("x1.enabled")
@Component
public class X1 {
```

Then downstream projects would have to add `x1.enabled = true` to their `application.properties` file if they wanted to use `X1`.

Is this the way to do things or is there some other standard approach for bundling components for reuse?

I can think of other approaches, e.g.:

- Put each component in its own package and then downstream projects could use `@ComponentScan` to scan just the packages of the components they wanted to use.
- I could leave off `@Component` on the component classes and mark them abstract and then leave it to any downstream project to simply subclass the components they want and add `@Component` to the subclass.

The first of those ideas sounds like a complete hack, the second doesn't sound so bad but one has to create subclasses simply in order to enable something (but at least it's fairly explicit what you're doing).

Just to note - I'm using an all annotation based configuration with no XML.

Comment: I think there is no question to answer. This is what you are doing all the time in Spring normally, whenever you create some XML provider bean, a datasource, a transaction manager,  or any number of other beans. Now you are writing your own beans, and suddenly you don't know what to do?

Comment: Thanks @Snickers3192 - a snide comment is always more helpful than a clear answer. If you're saying I can create components in my subproject in just the same way I create beans then this is not the case - at least not the way I create beans. I typically do so in a class named something like `XxxConfig` that's annotated with `@Configuration` and then contains a set of methods each annotated with `@Bean`. I cannot instead annotate one of these methods with `@Component` in order to create a component rather than a bean. If you know how to do this please provide an answer that can be voted on.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from creating another configuration with the beans you desire.

Answer (score 0):

The first option that you proposed, to me is a good option. You can put your classes in different packages and the scan the packages that you're interested in.

But you don't like the first option, so I suggest you the following.

You can take off the @component, of your classes and defined as beans in the configuration (xml files or @configuration classes). At the end each project configure the classes that it needs.

You then can inject those beans into others beans of the every project.

Answer (score 0):

To clear up a little confusion upon reading this question:

- Using @Bean before a method/parameter name (in your @Configuration) will create a bean named the same as that method/parameter (by default).  A function named myThing() will create a bean called "myThing"
- Using @Component before a class name will create a bean with the same name except the first letter is lowercase.  A class named MyThing will create a bean called "myThing"

You can indeed use @ComponentScan to scan for every @Component below the provided package name.

If you don't like that, you can create methods or parameters in your @Configuration that create instances of each of @Component you want to use.

If the creation of your beans is complicated, you can use @Import to import the whole @Configuration from your library.